# How to Insert document to MongoDB and return the same document or it's ID back using InsertOneAsync in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm writing a generic method to act like data access layer to insert document to MongoDB using C# .Net. My method looks like below. Collection here is a MongoCollection retrieved from MongoDB.

```
public async T Create(T entity){
await Collection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
}
```

I want to return the entity inserted or it's ID which is auto generated by MongoDB back. InsertOneAsync method is returning a task. I tried changing it as below. But its's return type is void.

```
Collection.InsertOneAsync(entity).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Is there a way to get the id or entity back using InsertOneAsync method. I'm using MongoDB driver for C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ids in MongoDB are generated [on the client side](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/index.html).

> If the document does not specify an _id field, then MongoDB will add the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document before inserting. Most drivers create an ObjectId and insert the _id field, but the mongod will create and populate the _id if the driver or application does not.

In you case you can generate ObjectIds manually and return them from your method (using `ObjectId.GenerateNewId()`) or return entire object since MongoDB driver will set proper _id value if you use `[BsonId]` attribute

```
public async Task<T> Create(T entity) where T:class
{
    await Collection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

And pass a type parameter like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

Comment: so if client does not set id, InsertOneAsync will update the entity's id property? and when we return the same entity, it will be returned with generated id?

Comment: @Aravind exactly

Comment: this is not working as you said. It is just returning what we passed. The generated id is not returned.

Comment: @Aravind I've tested this really quickly in Console App using driver v 2.5.0 and following code: `var result = p.Create(new MyClass()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` and I'm getting generated ObjectId under `Id` property. Could you post your code ?

Comment: My bad.. you are right..

Answer (score 2):

A good solution consists in letting the client generate the `_id` for you.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(ObjectIdGenerator))]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string SomeStringProperty { get; set; }
    public DateTime SomeDateTimeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The `_id` is generated whenever an entity with null `_id` is inserted in the database, and it's up to the driver to provide an `_id` value before insertion.

In case you don't want to reference MongoDB library in your domain model (so as I prefer) you might simply define your entity as follows.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string SomeStringProperty { get; set; }
    public DateTime SomeDateTimeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then, use this code directly in the persistence layer to map your entity with the database.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyEntity>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapIdMember(c => c.Id)
        .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance)
        .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));
});
```

`string` Ids are easier to be handled in the code, though this way they are mapped as `ObjectId` within the database.

Be careful: if you use the async version of `InsertOne()` method, you must wait for the insert to be at least started before getting the `_id` value set by the driver.

Comment: Thank you @Marcello for the detailed answer.